# How to elegantly prove that one can always choose a closed chart within an open one on a manifold?

Tags: geometry, manifolds, differential

Let $C \subset U \subset M$ with C compact and U open.  For each $p \epsilon C$, choose a chart (x, V) with $\overline{V} \subset U$ and $x(p)=0$  This is just a bit from Spivak Vol1, p. 33-34.  What is the tersest or most elegant way to prove that we can always choose such a V?  The only way I can think of doing it is by using open rectangles in a chart and then using sub-rectangles but it would be kind of clunky.  Is there a quicker purely topological way of doing it?  The $x(p)=0$ part I don't really care about, but it makes me think that maybe I actually have to use a chart.  Just to make clear, the claim is obvious, but the tersest rigorous proof is not.

Comment: For what it's worth, your argument doesn't strike me as clunky. We have to choose an open neighborhood _compactly contained_ in an open set; shrinking in the usual topology on $\mathbf{R}^{n}$ is the natural way to achieve this.

Comment: I see.  Thanks.  Why do you say "compactly contained" when it is a matter of the closure of V?

Comment: One often says $V$ is _compactly contained_ in $U$, and writes $U \Subset V$ (the LaTeX command \Subset), to mean the closure of $V$ is contained in $U$. The term presumably arises because if $V$ is bounded in a Euclidean space, then $\overline{V}$ is compact. As you've noticed, the concept is useful enough to merit a shorthand.